# Laravel HTTP Client - Posting XML file as application/octet-stream

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, guzzle

I am trying to post to an external API, that accepts a XML file. The content type is `application/octet-stream`.

This is my code:

```php
return Http::withToken(config('sproom.auth_token'))
    ->withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream'
    ])
    ->attach('xml', file_get_contents('myfile.xml'), 'myfile')
    ->post('https://example.org/api/documents')->json();
```

When posting the above, I get an API error back: `Cannot find format for document`. No further documentation exists.

I am guessing that the xml file is not being sent correctly as `application/octet-stream`.

The external API is using Swagger as "documentation", and if I upload the XML file using the Swagger UI, I get a success response. Here in cURL:

```
curl -X POST "https://example.org/api/documents" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Authorization: Bearer vmFrxk2+7......." -H  "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -d {}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use the CURL classes instead? I remember having trouble with the HTTP client too and i switched to use `curl_init` and `curl_setopt` and all and had success with it. Maybe you give it a try and write your results ;)

Comment: @Paladin I don't think that is a good idea as you are using a framework to get OOPs but using curl_init which is procedural, wouldn't it create problem for someone else

Comment: you can use guzzle option of debug as true to check what is send as complete process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I ended up using Guzzle directly:

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . config('sproom.auth_token')]]);
try {
    return $client->request('POST', config('sproom.api_url') . '/api/documents', [
        'body' => file_get_contents('myfile.xml'),
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ]
    ])->getBody();
} catch (RequestException $exception) {
    return json_decode($exception->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the content type of the request is application/octet-stream, Also in the curl request you have written above has a -d

```
curl -X POST "https://example.org/api/documents" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Authorization: Bearer vmFrxk2+7......." -H  "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -d {}
```

This is what is written in man curl

> -d, --data 
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request  to  the  HTTP
> server,  in  the  same  way  that a browser does when a user has
> filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This  will
> cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Compare to -F, --form.

If you are using `->attach`, I guess the request should be multipart/form-data.
So please do see which one you need I guess you can't post files in application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

I don't think there is an option currently to attach content type to a file in attach(), so you can try using guzzle directly. It comes with laravel by default and httpclient is a wrapper over it to reduce the code.

Here is the direct guzzle code

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . config('sproom.auth_token')]]);
$client->request('POST', 'https://example.org/api/documents', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept'     => '*/*'
    ],
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'myfile',
            'contents' => file_get_contents('myfile.xml'),
            'headers'  => ['Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream'],
            'filename' => 'myfile.xml'
        ]
    ]
]);
```